# OpenWrt Router in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, openwrt

Ok, I am trying to build a test environment that consists of 3 computers and router in virtualbox.  The router is running openWRT and the computers are running Ubuntu 16.04 Server.  I have successfully setup the router to connect to the first computer but I'm running into trouble connecting the router to the second one.

In virtualbox I have adapter 1 set to "internal network" (named greenWire) and connected to the first machine (ubuntu 16.04 server).  This is the connection that is currently working.  I have adapter 2 setup as a natnetwork that connects to the outside world through the host (also working).

This is where I'm having trouble.  I have adapter 3 set to "internal network" (named redWire) connected to the second machine (also ubuntu 16.04 server).  I simply copied the config in openWrt at /etc/config/network as follows:

```
config interface 'lan'
      option ifname 'eth0'
      option type 'bridge'
      option proto 'static'
      option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
      option netmask '255.255.255.0'
config interface 'lan2'
      option ifname 'eth2'
      option type 'bridge'
      option proto 'static'
      option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
      option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

I'm pretty sure that this is the wrong way to configure this but I'm not sure what the right way is.  Finally, here is the weird part.  I've assigned static ip addresses to the machines via /etc/config/dhcp.  The second machine has the ip address that I have assigned to it but I cannot ping it from the router.  So it was able to communicate enough to get the IP address but it is not connected enough to ping.

I know this is a lot to take in and I thank you for actually making it to this point in my post.  Basically, I need to to know how to configure my virtualbox openWRT router in order to connect to 3 VMs.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Remarks: 1) A fixed IP address set up in a DHCP server is not called a static IP address. A static IP address is set in the device itself with the DHCP client disabled. 2) A router can't deal with two subnets which have the same IP address space. Assign 192.168.2 to lan2. 3) You may want to use bridged networking to be able to monitor the network traffic with wireshark or so on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'd like to have all three of the VMs on the same subnet. How do I connect them to the router in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Either the host must be a bridge them, then, or the router must be configured to bridge all virtual network interfaces. Not sure which of these two options is actually available.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the router can be configured to bridge them.